# The difference between use print and return in a loop

Tags: python, tuples

Okay what I want is remove the first element in each smaller tuples and separate them into two new tuple: (2,3) and (5,6).

`a = ((1,2,3),(4,5,6))`

```
def remove_1(tup):
    for r in tup:
        r = r[1:]
        return (r) 

def remove_2(tup):
    for r in tup:
        r = r[1:]
        print(r)

>>>remove_1(x)
(2, 3)
>>> remove_2(x)
(2, 3)
(5, 6)
```

Why does `remove_1` and `remove_2` gives different result, where `remove_2` is able to process the second tuple in A but `remove_1` does not?

How to make `remove_1` to return two tuple:

```
(2,3)
(5,6)
```

Comment: May you show your full code? I don't know what you say.

Comment: They both print `(5, 6)`, I didn't see any difference.

Comment: Your second function produces the **exact same result** as the first, albeit in a print. Perhaps you used the wrong indentation?

Comment: Your question would make more sense if the `return` and the `print()` were *part of the `for` loop*. `return` then exits the loop *immediately*, returning only the slice for the first tuple in `a`. The `print()` would not end the function, so you'd see a line printed for both tuples.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I believe you closed this in error. It is obvious the indentation is wrong and the problem is the assignment `r = r[1:]` (OP thinks it is altering the original data)

Comment: Aside: this does what you need, but doesn't answer your "*Why?*" question: `def remove_3(tup): return tuple(r[1:] for r in tup)`

Comment: @JBernardo: When I closed the question, it was not clear and the code did not clearly illustrate the problem.

Comment: The reason it is printing both and returning one is because of return vs print. When it returns it stops the for loop after one loop and returns (2,3) while print loops twice

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I have edit the question a bit and put the return and print line into the loop. I tried on IDLE and they give different results now..

Comment: @JBernardo so the mistake is the assignment? It would help if you can kindly explain a little more?

Comment: @MartijnPieters So please don't blindly close questions unless it is really problematic. That's why the default procedure requires 5 people to close

Comment: @JBernardo: Sorry, a question that is incomplete *should* be closed. And I did not do so blindly; perhaps you had missed the initial version. If you want to discuss this further, please take it to [meta].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `return` causes an immediate return from the function. The loop stops immediately and no more code is run in the function.

The print statement, on the other hand, simply prints the result to the screen. The loop is allowed to continue to process all items.

It may seem like `return` and `print` are synonymous when running interactively, but the are very, very different. You see what `return` "prints" only because you are running in an interactive environment.

> How to make remove_1 to return two tuple:

One way is to create a variable to hold intermediate results, and then return when the loop is finished. Notice in the following code that `return` is *outside* the loop.

```
def remove_1(tup):
    result = []
    for r in tup:
        r = r[1:]
        result.append(r)
    return tuple(result)
```

Comment: Ya...I started learning python not long ago so I cannot see much different between the two then. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

> What do I need to change to let the remove_1 return both tuples?

Try this:

```
def remove_1(tup):
    result = []
    for r in tup:
        result.append(r[1:])
    return result
```

If you want to return a tuple, you could do `return tuple(result)` instead.

Comment: Thank you ! Does `return (result,)` gives same thing as `return tuple(result)`?

Comment: @mshx I'm only just learning Python myself. I just tried `return (result,)`. It gave something, but I have no idea what. Perhaps somebody else will see this and tell us.

Comment: I realise its because I put `result = []` in the for loop...oppss.. :P thanks so much!